# Connect to external HTTPS REST API

Tags: apex, api, rest, security-token

I'm looking for a solution how to connect to external API with Salesforce. 
The API I want to connect with is a HTTPS url, with some parameters. (https://www.url.com?param=...)

Here is the code I wrote allready.

```
public static HttpResponse CallOut(String requestType, String sKeyword, String sCountry){
                              // get the cendris config for the respective environment
                              getCendrisConfig();  gets the authkey to authorize and sets it in the member variable ‘token’

                              // Create the request
                              HttpRequest oHttpRequest = new HttpRequest();
                              String endpoint = 'https://www.businessview.nl';
                              String sBodyRequest = '/publicapi/api/v1/' + requestType + '?region=' + sCountry + '&searchtext=' + sKeyword + '&accesstoken=' + token;

                              oHttpRequest.setEndpoint(endpoint + sBodyRequest);
                              oHttpRequest.setClientCertificateName('Cendris_Business_View'); // Self-Signed certificate
                              oHttpRequest.setBody(sBodyRequest);
                              system.debug('Endpoint:' + oHttpRequest.getEndpoint());
                              oHttpRequest.setTimeOut(20000);
                              oHttpRequest.setMethod('GET');
                              oHttpRequest.setHeader('Accept-Encoding','gzip,deflate');
                              Http http = new Http();
                              HttpResponse oResponse = http.send(oHttpRequest);
                              system.debug(oResponse.getBody());
                              return oResponse;
               }
```

If I put a request via SOAP UI, there is no problem. If I put the full URL in a browser, I get the data, but via this code in a class, executed via a anonymous execute, I receive a response I do an HTTP request, which is not allowed . It seems like Salesforce changes my HTTPS-request to an HTTP-request.

Things I did allready checked:
- Certificate self-signed is ok ?
- Remote site settings are ok.

Can anybody help ?

Kind regards,
Gunther

Comment: Do you maybe call this function from a trigger? Or in a loop maybe? Can you post the code you use to call the function? What is the exact error?

Comment: Hi Lex, No, not from a trigger, not in a loop. The code is above. I create an HTTP request to an HTTPS url, This is the request (I modified the access token):

12:57:02:069 CALLOUT_REQUEST [49]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://www.businessview.nl/publicapi/api/v1/searchCompanies?region=BE&searchtext=thomaes&accesstoken=***, Method=GET]

This is the response:
 {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.businessview.nl/publicapi/api/v1/searchCompanies?region=BE&searchtext=thomaes&accesstoken=***

Comment: Ah, that seems like an actual message from the third party. Are you sure you're calling the correct endpoint? It seems like your just trying to use a resource that isn't support at their end. Seeing as you're actually getting an HTTP response in Salesforce, it seems the actual callout is being done properly.

Comment: Hi Lex,
It is the endpoint provided by the 3th Party. A few hours ago, I contacted the Third party. They will investigate the issue. I think that my request will interpreted as http request, while I send an HTTPS request.
I will let you know what the result was
Kind Regards,
Gunther